# jQuery Ajax call on HTTPS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, https

I have a form that takes three steps to fill it.
At each of these steps you fill some info, click "Next" and then see either errors you have to fix in order to get to the next step or if there are no errors it takes you to the next step (change "display" to "block" in CSS).

At first step it uses $.ajax() to call file **lib/ajax.php** which returns some results in JSON that matter a lot to filling the rest of the form.
The thing is this works locally on my http://my.dev address, but live on https://something.example.com it does not.

Where should I first try looking to go about it? What are the most common workarounds on this?

Both **lib/ajax.php** and the **index.php** file (that has the jQuery call) are on the same domain (https://something.example.com) so we are not talking about cross-domain calls.

Here's some of the code.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'lib/ajax.php', 
   async: false,
   data: {id: id}, 
   dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
   }).done(function(data){
       // do stuff with data
});
```

and the **lib/ajax.php**

```
//stuff with db and retrieving row by id
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($result);
```

That's pretty much it. It doesn't work when I place it on live HTTPS server.

Comment: Can you please post some code reference?

Comment: or at least show the link you are using in the $.post function ?

Comment: Added some code guys.

Comment: And what does "nor work" mean exactly? Will the ajax request be fired, do you receive a server response with a HTTP code back? Or doesn't it even send the ajax request?

Comment: How do you check on that?

I did a simple alert('here') in the script just before the ajax call, and fair enough the alert did display. Then I did alert('here2') in the ajax.done() call but it didn't work.

Comment: try to change the `type` instead of `get` use `post`

Comment: console log `data` in the `.done()`

Comment: @skip405 it didn't work, same as `alert('something')` didn't work in `.done()`.
@SudhanshuSaxena doesn't work.

Comment: as you can check on `success` and `error` calls to see what is going on

Comment: if `.done()` is not working - log in the console something from the `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {})`

Comment: Thanks @skip405, you rock! Didn't know about the `.fail()` method and this saved me now. You learn something every day. Cheers pal!

Comment: @ToniPerić no worries, but surely `.fail()` can't solve a problem for you :) as it's... well, a failure )) But it will definitely guide you in the right direction. If you manage to solve you problem it will be fine if you answer your question yourself, for the future visitors of this question. Cheers )

Comment: The problem actually had nothing to do with jQuery/Ajax whatsoever.
The lib/ajax.php was actually connecting to external database, which only accepted connections from my IP address but not the IP address of the server. That was the error `.fail()` returned as it couldn't connect to the DB at all. Just had to allow connections to MySQL from server's IP as well and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

In https i think you must change the `dataType: 'json'` to `dataType: 'jsonp'`

Comment: That's only needed for cross domain calls afaik. But the questioner want to call a URI in the same domain origin.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I just tried it but unfortunately it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check the whether the url given in the function $.ajax() is the right path or not.

2.Here you specified data type as "JSON",so response must be "JSON".

3.If the response is not in correct JSON format,it makes issue.

```
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Add the above code in $.ajax()  function

Please check the above specified points

Comment: 1. It is relative and works on localhost, it's lib/ajax.php;
2. It is.;
3. It is JSON. It always is, even if the error occurs it gives back the errors in json.

Comment: Check the response and post the response here,then i can tell u clearly,if you getting any error,post that error too.

Comment: The script doesn't get through to the `.done()` method. It does however display `alert('something')` just before the ajax call is supposed to be run. How can I get the response/error then?

Comment: $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'lib/ajax.php', 
   async: false,
   data: {id: id}, Try this instead of .done()
   dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the  success: function(data){
                alert("Return OK");
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert('ERROR = ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + thrownError);
            } 
});

Comment: Yes, it returned the error that helped me. Thank you very much for helping me out, Udhay.